# How to start a linux distribution and hide the starting notice?

Tags: linux, debian, startup

For some usrs, i'm installing a Debian 5.0 on their laptops.
And when the system starts, they are scared of all the 'hacking-like' codes that the system notices.

It is useful for me, but not for them.

So my question is how can i hide those notices ? and replace them by spinner, or any progress bar.

I would have liked to do Windows XP like starting.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're installing Debian on someone who isn't used to Linux, I'd recommend using Ubuntu instead. It's a little bit more user friendly on the desktop and has a splash start up screen.

Ubuntu is pretty much identical to Debian in most respects as far as you would be concerned.

If you must use Debian, investigate [USplash](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/usplash), which is what Ubuntu uses, but is already integrated. I couldn't tell you how simple it is to use.

Answer (score 2):

I second the suggestion to consider Ubuntu.  Debian-based, already does a splash-screen out of the box, and otherwise less likely to confuse inexperienced users.

For debian, look at [splashy](http://splashy.alioth.debian.org/wiki/), which looks like it's the preferred Debian way to do this, and there's [packages for it in lenny](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/splashy). I've never personally done anything with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a framebuffer splash screen.

Here's a howto:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=41709